# Why did the Visual Basic IDE stop filling in the rest of a property when creating a new property in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, templates, properties

For some reason, when I'm creating a new property in Visual Basic .NET in Visual Studio 2010, the rest of the Property (template?) doesn't complete the basic framework of the property in the code editor. It is now treating a statement like:

```
Public Property Length() As Integer
```

Instead of completing the property as it used to (code follows), it simply goes to the next line:

```
Public Property Length() As Integer
    Get

    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)

    End Set
End Property
```

What happens now is that, if I type in the 'End Property' code, the name of the property will now be highlighted as an error since it doesn't have a 'Get' or 'Set' portion.

However, when I THEN type the 'Get' on the line following the 'Public Property Length() As Integer', then the balance of the property is created in the code automatically.

I don't know how this got changed, but would love to change it back.

Does anyone know if there's a setting in VS2010 that addresses this, or if it's something with the basic templates that visual studio uses for creating the basic code components?

The weird thing is that for everything else, from class declarations, structures, functions and subs, the IDE still creates the balance of the code structure correctly. The only area where it doesn't is for Property declarations.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Kevin

Comment: Type "prop" and press the Tab key twice.

Comment: and that will implement the code snippet for a property. Got it! :-)  Thanks also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET version 10 has [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx).

These are a bit of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that for simple properties (those that only get/set values of a field and nothing else) allow you to omit the Get/Set portions and the field (these *do* get generated by the compiler).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was unaware of this change to the language elements in Visual Basic in VS2010. Your answer (and most especially the link to the MSDN entry) was EXACTLY what I needed to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As [Oded mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022459/why-did-the-visual-basic-ide-stop-filling-in-the-rest-of-a-property-when-creatin/8022484#8022484), this is because VB 10 now allows you to simply have:

```
Public Property Length() As Integer
```

and it will be auto-implemented as:

```
Private _length As Integer
Public Property Length() As Integer
    Get
        Return _length
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _length = value
    End
End Property
```

This is the same as C#'s syntax allowing you to have:

```
public int Length { get; set; }
```

So from the IDE's perspective, there's no *need* to generate all that code, as the compiler will essentially be the one doing it.

Of course, this isn't always desirable. You often actually want to implement a property yourself without having to do the boilerplate part. This is where I think you're coming from with this question.

I *believe* you can still accomplish what you're after using code snippets. Visual Studio has a bunch of these. Last I checked, typing "Prop" and hitting tab would still create all the above boilerplate. I may be wrong about that (not on a Windows machine at the moment); but even if I am, you should be able to create your own snippet that will generate the boilerplate you want.

To get back to your question of "Why?" however: I think the IDE team made the right choice here. Given that VB 10 *does* support auto-implemented properties (for better or worse), developers would be very frustrated if every time they wanted an auto-implemented property the IDE automatically generated a ton of boilerplate, which would then need to be deleted. Going the other way, while it can be annoying, seems much more reasonable (especially given the code snippet option I already mentioned).

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with your statement that the IDE team made the right choice for implementing this. I simply was unaware of the concept and specific change in the IDE for this. A good "fix" (not sure I should call it that) is listed on MSDN, and that is to begin to type "G" on the line immediately following the declaration, and then hit <enter>, and the rest of the boilerplate will be generated.  Thanks also for the feedback. I genuinely appreciate it.